# using GCS path in PyPDF2 PdfFileReader

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, pypdf

I am using the python library PyPDF2 and trying to read a pdf file using PdfFileReader. It works fine for a local pdf file. Is there a way to access my pdf file from Google Cloud Storage bucket (gs://bucket_name/object_name)?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

with open('testpdf.pdf','rb') as f1:
        reader = PdfReader(f1)
        number_of_pages = len(reader.pages)
```

Instead of 'testpdf.pdf', how can I provide my Google Cloud Storage object location? Please let me know if anyone tried this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GCSFS library to access files from gcs bucket. For eg.

```py
import gcsfs
from pypdf import PdfReader

gcs_file_system = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project="PROJECT_ID")
gcs_pdf_path = "gs://bucket_name/object.pdf"

f_object = gcs_file_system.open(gcs_pdf_path, "rb")
    
# Open our PDF file with the PdfReader
reader = PdfReader(f_object)
  
# Get number of pages
num = len(reader.pages)

f_object.close()
```

Comment: `PyPDF2` is now back to `pypdf`.